# Find the image of the function $f:[−10,10]→R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2+2x+2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm learning about relations in discrete math, but I'm still not sure if I'm correct about my resolution, so I'd like someone to look at my train of thought and tell me if there's something wrong or if it's correct.

**Question**
Find the image of the function $f:[−10,10]→R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2+2x+2$

**My attempt**

I need to find the function image. To do this, I must replace *x* by the intervals of the function.

Intervals: [-10, 10]
x: $f(x) = x^2 +2x +2$

So putting the two intervals, it would be:

$f(-10) = (-10)^2 + 2. (-10) + 2$
$f(-10) = 100 + (-20)+2$
$f(-10) = 100 + (-18)$
$f(-10) = 82$

$f(10) = 10^2 + 2. 10 + 2$
$f(10) = 100 + 20+2$
$f(10) = 100 + 22$
$f(10) = 122$

So the function image would be:

$Im = [82, 122]$

Does it makes sense? I'm not entirely correct about the resolution, if anyone can look into it I'm grateful.

Comment: HINT: Plot the function https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2B2x%2B2+from+x%3D-10+to+x%3D10 Also $(-10)^2 \neq -100$.

Comment: The square of -10 is 100 not -100. Generally finding the image of a function is quite complicated but if the function is monotonic (increasing or decreasing). Can you break down the function in monotonic pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can complete the square to find $f(x) = (x+1)^2 +1$. It becomes clear from here that the minimum is at $x = -1$ and the maximum is at $x= 10 $.

Comment: Following your lead, this would only fit if there wasn't a restriction on ranges, wouldn't it? So it would be: $[1, +∞[$?

Comment: What do you mean by "fit". Moreover, there is no restriction on the range. We're looking for the image. You can find the image by finding the minimum and maximum values. Then the image is $[f(\text{min}), f(\text{max})]$. I completed the square because that makes it clear what the min and max are.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks